# Event end of selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, events

On an Angular / Ionic mobile app, I'm looking for a way to add an event at the end of a text selection.
I've tried pretty much every Angular event: every mouse/scroll events, touchend, pressup, panup, selectionchange, select...

All these events work on pc but not when you select text on mobile (with the context menu).
[context menu on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUx85.png)

I think it's because when we click on the arrows (see image), we are not clicking on the application, but on the context menu generated by the phone's OS.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onselect

Comment: Check this, it works for all browsers, and as i know it works on textarea and not just input... it works on mobile as u want. Just hope u reply back if that is what u want so i can help if not or post it as answer in case thats the solution..